# Python Serial works in shell but not script?

Tags: python, shell, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying out an example on Arduino: http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Python

The example (running on Ubuntu) works great in the shell:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while True:
    print(ser.readline())
```

However attempting to execute as a script:

**Desktop/python_arduino/./serial.py**...

Which executes this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while True:
    print(ser.readline())
```

And I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/python_arduino/./serial.py", line 2, in <module>
    import serial
  File "/home/leo/Desktop/python_arduino/serial.py", line 4, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'
```

What is causing this inconsistency? It should be easy to `import serial` regardless of shell or script right?

Comment: What was causing the behaviour you observed?

Comment: See my answer below. The script filename was the same name as the import.

So the filename was serial.py. The module is called serial.

I changed the script's filename, and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FOUND IT!

The issue was actually subtle yet simple.

*The script filename was the same name as the import.*

So the filename was **serial.py**. The module is called **serial**, so it created a conflict.

I changed the script's filename, and it worked.

Comment: I had to delete the `.pyc` file as well.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the shell and your script may be different path setups. Compare the paths and see if anything differs for the script vs. the shell

```
import ser
print ser.__file__

import sys
print sys.executable
```